# Compress files in a directory in a zip file with the shell

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I want to compress files from the filesystem to a directory within a new zip archive or update an old one. So here is my example:

```
directory/
  |-file1.ext
  |-file2.ext
  |-file3.ext
```

in the zip archive it should look like this:

```
new_directory/
  |-file1.ext
  |-file2.ext
  |-file3.ext
```

I could copy the files to a new directory and compress them from there but i do not want to have that extra step. I haven't found an answer to that problem on google. The man page doesn't mention anything like that aswell so I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the `zip` utility supports this sort of transformation. A workaround is to use a symbolic link:

```
ln -s directory new_directory
zip -r foo.zip new_directory
rm new_directory
```

**If other archive formats are an option for you,** then this would be a bit easier with a tar archive, since GNU tar has a `--transform` option taking a sed command that it applies to the file name before adding the file to the archive.

In that case, you could use (for example)

```
tar czf foo.tar.gz --transform 's:^directory/:new_directory/:' directory
```

Comment: Thanks, tar is not an option for me, but the symbolic link is a good solution didn't thought about that in the first place.